# TypeScript sorting array of objects by its properties

Tags: typescript, sorting, object

Hello everyone i have problem with array sorting.

This is my array of Objects and i would like to  create methods to sort it by its properties both ways (ascending / descending ).

```js
this.products = [
  {productId: 1, manufacturer: "toshiba", model: "ZXT120", description: "Good gaming laptop", quantity: 1},
  {productId: 2, manufacturer: "lenovo", model: "ZXT120", description: "Good gaming laptop", quantity: 1},
  {productId: 3, manufacturer: "DM", model: "ZXT120", description: "Good gaming laptop", quantity: 1},
  {productId: 4, manufacturer: "Asus", model: "ZXT120", description: "Good gaming laptop", quantity: 1},
  {productId: 5, manufacturer: "RX200", model: "ZXT120", description: "Good gaming laptop", quantity: 1},
]
```

This is what i came up with but i am repeating myself in each method for example sortByModel() uses the same logic but as method given below but  on different properties
I am looking for a way to create more generic method and  refactor it but i dont have any ideas

```js
sortByManufacturer() {
  if (this.manufacturerSorted) {
    this.manufacturerSorted = !this.manufacturerSorted;
    this.products.sort((a, b) => a.manufacturer.localeCompare(b.manufacturer))
  } else {
    this.manufacturerSorted = !this.manufacturerSorted;
    this.products.sort((a, b) => b.manufacturer.localeCompare(a.manufacturer))
  }
}
```

Comment: You can try letting `sortByModal()` accepting the target property name to sort as its argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this,

```
 sortByManufacturer(keyToSortBy: string, order = 'asc') {
    if (keyToSortBy) {
      this.manufacturerSorted = !this.manufacturerSorted;
    if(order === 'asc')
      this.products.sort((a, b) => a[keyToSortBy].toLowerCase() < b[keyToSortBy].toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1)
    else
       this.products.sort((a, b) => a[keyToSortBy].toLowerCase() > b[keyToSortBy].toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1

    } 
  }
```

Comment: Thank you , this is what i was looking for

Comment: Glad it worked out :).. Can you mark my answer as accepted though..